# PowerBI: copy previous dates values in case of missing dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a rather large table in PowerBI that looks as follows:

| Date1 | ID1 | ID2 | Date2 | Amount1 | Amount2 | Amount3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04.02.2022 | 1234 | 12 | 04.02.2022 | 5 | 3 | 8 |
| 04.02.2022 | 1234 | 13 | 04.02.2022 | 5 | 3 | 8 |
| 04.02.2022 | 1235 | 14 | 04.02.2022 | 6 | 3 | 9 |
| 06.02.2022 | 1234 | 10 | 06.02.2022 | 20 | 23 | 46 |
| 06.02.2022 | 1238 | 11 | 06.02.2022 | 20 | 23 | 46 |
| 06.02.2022 | 1238 | 14 | 06.02.2022 | 26 | 23 | 49 |

As in the case above, if e.g. 05.02.2022 is missing, I would like my end result to look like

| Date1 | ID1 | ID2 | Date2 | Amount1 | Amount2 | Amount3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04.02.2022 | 1234 | 12 | 04.02.2022 | 5 | 3 | 8 |
| 04.02.2022 | 1234 | 13 | 04.02.2022 | 5 | 3 | 8 |
| 04.02.2022 | 1235 | 14 | 04.02.2022 | 6 | 3 | 9 |
| 05.02.2022 | 1234 | 12 | 05.02.2022 | 5 | 3 | 8 |
| 05.02.2022 | 1234 | 13 | 05.02.2022 | 5 | 3 | 8 |
| 05.02.2022 | 1235 | 14 | 05.02.2022 | 6 | 3 | 9 |
| 06.02.2022 | 1234 | 10 | 06.02.2022 | 20 | 23 | 46 |
| 06.02.2022 | 1238 | 11 | 06.02.2022 | 20 | 23 | 46 |
| 06.02.2022 | 1238 | 14 | 06.02.2022 | 26 | 23 | 49 |

Which means that everything from 04.02.2022 is copy pasted, just with a new date, 05.02.2022.

There are also cases where **no data is available for 2 or 3 days**, so in those instances I would need the all data from the last known date, until we have data again.

Does someone know how to implement this in PowerBI?

Thank you!

Comment: how many rows do you have in table aprox.? You have missed ID2 12 and 13 for 06do you want to repeat then as also?

Comment: ~35k rows. ID2 can be different for 06.02.2022, that's fine. The important thing is that all the data from 04.02.2022 should show up 1:1 (with a new date, in this case 05.02.2022) until we have data again (in this example until 06.02.2022)

Comment: Are your ids correct on the 06.02? The same ids don't show up so why would the ones repeated for the 05.02 not also repeat for the 06.02?

Comment: Yes, the IDs are correct as they are. On 06.02. we don't have results for certain IDs or the ordering is such that they show up later. Regardless, the aim remains that all the data from 04.02.2022 should show up 1:1 (with a new date, in this case 05.02.2022) until we have data again (in this example until 06.02.2022)

Comment: The real question is: Why do you believe you need this data? What do you want to do with it? It is maybe not needed to generate many extra rows what is creating extra memory consumption and might slow things down..

Comment: I need this data because the column "Amount3" is part of a prediction value that needs to be plotted on a daily basis. If e.g. for technical reasons there's no value for 05.02.2022 the predicted value will show a massive dip on 05.02.2022 because "Amount3" cannot contribute to it. Therefore, if this value is not available, we want to display the previous' days prediction, until we have data again (06.02.2022).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work for you. I have named your sample data query as Table.

[image]

Create a new query and paste in the following code. This new query refers to your sample data query named Table so you will have two queries.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjDRMzDSMzIwMlKK1QFyTVG5ZghuLAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Date = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"Date"}, Table, {"Date1"}, "Table", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Count", each if Table.RowCount([Table]) > 0 then [Table] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Count"}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filled Down", "Custom", each if Table.RowCount([Table]) > 0 then [Table] else Table.ReplaceValue([Count],[Count]{0}[Date1],[Date],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Date1", "Date2"})),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Table", "Count"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", {"Date1", "ID1", "ID2", "Date2", "Amount1", "Amount2", "Amount3"}, {"Date1", "ID1", "ID2", "Date2", "Amount1", "Amount2", "Amount3"}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"Date"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

If you need to fill out more dates, then just change the date range in step 1 which you should be able to auto generate depending on your data. Mine looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, step 4
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Count", each if Table.RowCount([Table]) > 0 then [Table] else null)
always results in an error for me, because I don't have a column of the name [Table]. I tried replacing this with other column names but this also doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Your original query should be named Table or you can change the reference to whatever your query name is. If you follow the instructions word for word, it works or you can make changes to suit your set up.